# Does Java Iterator hold reference to elements of a linked list?

Tags: java, pointers, object, iterator

I need to have a list to hold several elements of an Enemy class in an app. This will function as an object pool to increase efficiency, as this particular class would otherwise be instantiated and killed off often.

I am so far probably going to use a linked list as it would be strongly beneficial to put inactive elements to the end of the list. My question is the following - in Java, does the Iterator provide direct access to the current element it is accessing by holding a reference to it (for linked lists), or does iterating to the next element require the Iterator to cycle from the beginning again (i.e. doesn't help efficiency, like a for loop which will always require going back to beginning for a linked list)?

From a C perspective, my question would be whether the Iterator contains a pointer to the current element it is accessing so that it doesn't have to loop from the beginning to gain access.

I have done some research on this, but I haven't been able to find an answer to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not documented in the Javadoc, but you can check the implementation of `LinkedList`'s `listIterator` and see that it does hold a reference to the current and next elements of the List :

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    return new ListItr(index);
}

private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Entry<E> lastReturned = header;
    private Entry<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;
    ....
```

It only has to iterate over the LinkedList (from the start or from the end) when the `ListIterator` is created, since you can request the `ListIterator` to point to a specific index of the List when it's constructed.

Comment: I was just about to say this :) It's also worth noting that if the `ListItr` didn't keep a reference to the current element, iterating the list (even with a "for" loop) would be prohibitively expensive and would happen in O(n^2) time

Comment: Where can I access this?

Comment: excessive O(n^2) time was indeed what I was worried about

Comment: @SuperHacker You can download the JDK with source code, and have it accessible from your IDE. Or you can search for it online (for example, you can Google "grep code java LinkedList".

Comment: @SuperHacker or see my answer which has a link

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `Iterator` implementation used in LinkedList keeps references to the next **and previous** elements for efficient iteration.

Java is open source, you can look at the code yourself.  [Here's the Linked List Iterator code  code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr)

```
private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Node<E> lastReturned;
    private Node<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;

    ListItr(int index) {
        // assert isPositionIndex(index);
        next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
        nextIndex = index;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextIndex < size;
    }

    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        lastReturned = next;
        next = next.next;
        nextIndex++;
        return lastReturned.item;
    }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> This will function as an object pool to increase efficiency, as this particular class would otherwise be instantiated and killed off often.

I wouldn't use an object pool unless either your object is very expensive or it is called a lot, like say one million times per second.  Note: using a LinkedList will create objects to add it to the list so you might not be saving as much as you think.

> I am so far probably going to use a linked list as it would be strongly beneficial to put inactive elements to the end of the list.

The build in LinkedLIst isn't good for this but creating your own might work.  Adding to the end of the list is expensive, but adding to the start is relatively cheap.  I would do that instead as the order shouldn't matter.

> My question is the following - in Java, does the Iterator provide direct access to the current element it is accessing by holding a reference to it (for linked lists),

Yes.

> or does iterating to the next element require the Iterator to cycle from the beginning again (i.e. doesn't help efficiency)?

Also yes.

> From a C perspective, my question would be whether the Iterator contains a pointer to the current element it is accessing so that it doesn't have to loop from the beginning to gain access.

I wouldn't use the Iterator at all.  This more garbage and overhead.  However if you need to rewind you can use with ListIterator, or you have to create a new Iterator.

Comment: hmmm I'm definitely not hitting 1 million per second. You've persuaded me to abandon the object pool

Comment: @SuperHacker I suggest you use a memory profiler to see where you allocating the most objects are find ways to reduce the biggest by size or by number.  Creating an average object takes about 30 ns.

Comment: Good point on the object pooling; Java's GC strategies also tend to favor small, short-term objects over long-term objects, which become tenured and harder to GC. But not quite sure what you mean by "also yes" in response to cycling from the beginning -- `ListItr` certainly does not go back to the beginning of the list in each `next()` call

Comment: @user2221343 yes but not Iterator.

Comment: Also on your last point, note that for-each syntax (`for ( .. : ..)`) is just sugar for an iterator. Using an iterator would not incur any performance penalty over using a for-each loop, unless the JVM does some odd optimization here.

Comment: @user2221343 Java 8 does have an optimisation called Escape Analysis and it can place the Iterator on the stack. It can do this no matter how you create it.  However, if all you need is an object pool, you can add free resources to the head and obtain resource from the head, no need for an Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

> does iterating to the next element require the Iterator to cycle from the beginning again

You can rest assured this is not true exactly *because* it would be such a suicidal design decision. The whole point of `Iterator` is allowing an optimal access pattern for sequential-access data structures.

I must also add this: from both the performance and memory standpoints, you would be better served by an `ArrayList`. The extra node elements required by `LinkedList` induce a large overhead and, in addition to that, the pointer-chasing access pattern inherent to linked lists is cache-unfriendly.